# Linear dependence/independence of vectors as linear combinations of basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have two vector $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ and they form a basis for a plane $P$. Now define two new vectors, $\mathbf{w}_1$ and $\mathbf{w}_2$, which are a linear combination of the basis vectors $\mathbf{v}_i, i = 1, 2$, for example: $$\mathbf{w}_1 = \frac{7}{6}\mathbf{v}_1 - \frac{2}{3}\mathbf{v}_2 \quad \text{and} \quad \mathbf{w}_2 -\frac{1}{3}\mathbf{v}_1 - \frac{1}{6}\mathbf{v}_2.$$

Is it possible to deduce anything about the linear dependence/independence of the vectors $\mathbf{w}_i, i = 1, 2$? If they are linearly independent, do they also form a basis for $P$, i.e. do they span the plane?

Comment: Yeah, as the vectors are a combination of v1 and v2, they will also lie in the plane and if they are linearly independent, then they will also span the plane because you can always get back v1 and v2 from these vectors. You can see this with normal i,j,k unit vectors also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\mathbf{w}_1=a_{11}\mathbf{v}_1+a_{12}\mathbf{v}_2$ and $\mathbf{w}_2=a_{21}\mathbf{v}_1+a_{22}\mathbf{v}_2$, then $\mathbf{w}_1$ and $\mathbf{w}_2$ are linearly independent if and only if$$\det\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}\neq0.$$On the other hand, $\mathbf{w}_1$ and $\mathbf{w}_2$ are linearly independent if and only if $\{\mathbf{w}_1,\mathbf{w}_2\}$ is a basis of $P$.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. I'm accepting your answer since it described the exact method I was looking for in order to determine linear dependence/independence.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can verify that does not exists a real number $k$ such that $\mathbf w_1=k \mathbf w_2$ and this means that the two vectors are linearly independent. In general the two vectors are linearly dependent is such a number $k$ exists (and is not null).

And the two vectors, being linearly independent, span the same subspace as $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a_1w_1+a_2w_2=0$. It is equivalent to $(\frac{7}{6}a_1-\frac{1}{3}a_2)v_1+(-\frac{2}{3}a_1-\frac{1}{6}a_2)v_2=0$. Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, we should have $\frac{7}{6}a_1=\frac{1}{3}a_2$ and $-\frac{2}{3}a_1=\frac{1}{6}a_2$, which is equivalent to $a_1=a_2=0$. Thus $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent.

Also, they span plane, because arbitrary vector on plane can be expressed as $b_1v_1+b_2v_2=(-6b_1-12b_2)(\frac{7}{6}v_1-\frac{2}{3}v_2)+(24b_1+42b_2)(\frac{1}{3}v_1-\frac{1}{6}v_2)$
$=(-6b_1-12b_2)w_{1}+(24b_1+42b_2)w_2$.